# Proper way to exit command line program?

Tags: unix, terminal

I'm using mac/linux and I know that ctrl-z stops the currently running command in terminal, but I frequently see the process is still running when i check the system monitor. What is the right way to stop a command in terminal?

Typically I run into this issue when running python or ruby apps, i'm not sure if that has something to do with it, just thought I would add that.

Comment: if you do ctrl-z and then type exit it will close background applications.

Comment: i still see the process after running exit

Comment: also, i have to force quit the process from activity monitor as opposed to just quitting it to get it to stop, that could mostly be a fault of the type of program i was running, but i felt it was worth mentioning

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Using <kbd>control-z</kbd> suspends the process (see the output from `stty -a` which lists the key stroke under `susp`).  That leaves it running, but in suspended animation (so it is not using any CPU resources).  It can be resumed later.

If you want to stop a program permanently, then any of interrupt (often <kbd>control-c</kbd>) or quit (often <kbd>control-\</kbd>) will stop the process, the latter producing a core dump (unless you've disabled them).  You might also use a HUP or TERM signal (or, if really necessary, the KILL signal, but try the other signals first) sent to the process from another terminal; or you could use <kbd>control-z</kbd> to suspend the process and then send the death threat from the current terminal, and then bring the (about to die) process back into the foreground (`fg`).

Note that all key combinations are subject to change via the `stty` command or equivalents; the defaults may vary from system to system.

Comment: Nice answer. I'd also mention `bg` which is the opposite of `fg`. It allows you to resume your program execution in the background so that you can use your terminals for something else. Something related is `disown` which allows you to detach your background program from the terminal so that it continues running even if you close the terminal. To see what jobs your shell is controlling, use the `jobs` command.

Answer (score 3):

if you do `ctrl-z` and then type `exit` it will close background applications.

`Ctrl+Q` is another good way to kill the application.

Comment: What key is `control-q` mapped to on your system?  It is normally the `start` (for resuming output after using `control-s` to stop the output).

Comment: I just notice actually after testing that this only works on my Mac. I thought it was universal. When to mint and tried it after noticing no one posted it as an option. and it `ctrl-shift-q`. but all that did for me in linux was close the terminal. Not what the user wants.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Job Control on UNIX systems](http://acs.ucsd.edu/info/jobctrl.shtml)

If you don't have control of your shell, simply hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> should stop the process. If that doesn't work, you can try <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> and using the `jobs` and `kill -9 %<job #>` to kill it. The '-9' is a type of signal. You can `man kill` to see a list of signals.