How to change CtrlBreak hotkey on VSCode Integrated Terminal to send Sigterm to running application
We can send CtrlBreak using Ctrl+\ on VSCode, I don't see any Keyboard Shortcut regarding this hotkey in the settings. I want to know if it's possible to change this hotkey to something else? Because I'm using this hotkey for something else.
The reason I need to send CtrlBreak is this: Stopping python using ctrl+c
And I've already tried this and I can confirm it does not send CtrlBreak, it sends ^c: Make Ctrl+C=copy and Ctrl+Shift+C=interrupt in VSCode terminal
I should also note that I'm on Linux mostly and this hotkey works fine and on Windows I tried on CMD, Powershell and Windows Terminal and this hotkey also works on all three but not in VSCode's integrated terminal, so if we have a way to change the CtrlBreak hotkey maybe it would help the case on Windows too!

answer is in last line of https://stackoverflow.com/a/8221984/11107541

@starball That link does not answer my question. That does not work on WSL2 or Windows. I'm asking for a way to send HUP or TERM or KILL to the Terminal using VSCode's keybinds.

I'm on Windows and sometimes I develop on WSL2 so I was looking for an OS agnostic way to handle this, inside VSCode, the link is for Linux. As I said in question I'm on Linux mostly too but I also develop on WSL2, Windows etc.


that doesn't make sense. ctrl+\ is bound to the quit signal. the quit signal is not hup, term, or kill. 2) your question post doesn't mention WSL. does ctrl+\ send a quit signal on windows (not in WSL)?


I don't understand how this doesn't answer the question. the question is "I want to know if it's possible to change this hotkey to something else?". you do that through stty. it doesn't have anything to do with VS Code. and your last paragraph is quite confusing.

As I said, Ctrl+\ on cmd, pwsh, wt sends quit to the program running but on VSCode's integrated terminal, Ctrl+\ does not quit the program. So I was looking for a way to send a signal to integrated terminal, maybe even through the command pallet. see this https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/189908 @starball

As I asked how to do this on Linux+Windows, how can I change that hotkey throught stty on Windows? your comment does not make any sense. You did not understand the question, instead of asking for clarification, it was outright closed.

"but on VSCode's integrated terminal, Ctrl+\ does not quit the program" no repro on Ubuntu 24. what shell are you using in VS Code's integrated terminal?

Please copy and paste the output of the Help: About command (run in the command palette) into your question post.
